# Slick 2: How to write DB-agnostic DAL code

Tags: scala, slick

This is basically the repeat of an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661339/slick-how-to-write-db-agnostic-apps-and-perform-first-time-db-initialization), but with respect to **Slick-2**, as the answers that worked for v.1 don't work anymore.

In short, Slick documentation suggests to do something like this

```
package models
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

class Pictures(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String)](tag, "Pictures") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def urlThumb = column[String]("urlThumb", O.NotNull)
    def urlLarge = column[String]("urlLarge", O.NotNull)
    def * = (id, urlThumb, urlLarge)
}
```

This is tying the code directly to H2Driver. I want it to be driver-agnostic, i.e. to work with any JdbcProfile driver. The only way I found to do it is by passing the driver to the DAO class

```
class SlickDAO(val driver: JdbcProfile) {
    import driver.simple._
```

The problem with that is if I want to define some traits with shared behavior, e.g. CRUDSupport, I can't have arguments to the trait, I can only do an abstract class. So I am curious what is the **recommended** way of writing the DAL with Slick-2?  I'm sure it's the Cake pattern, but I am not advanced enough in Scala to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know specifically about Slick, but there are standard Scala approaches to this problem.

> I can't have arguments to the trait, I can only do an abstract class

But you can have

```
trait SlickDAO {
  val driver: JdbcProfile

  import driver.simple._
  ...
}
```

and later

```
class SlickDAOImpl(val driver: JdbcProfile) extends SlickDAO
```

or

```
 new SlickDAO {
   val driver = ...
 }
```

However, using abstract `val`s in traits can lead to problems with initialization order, so I'd prefer

```
trait SlickDAO {
  // can still be implemented as a val
  def driver: JdbcProfile

  // can't import driver.simple._, you'll have to write the prefix explicitly
  ...
}
```

or

```
trait SlickDAO {
  def getDriver: JdbcProfile
  lazy val driver = getDriver

  import driver.simple._
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have found an example of using this exact approach: https://github.com/rcavalcanti/slick-dao

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://knoldus.wordpress.com/?p=5228&preview=true
and   :https://github.com/satendrakumar06/slickformultipledatabases
it might be helpful.