# Slick generic AND driver agnostic

Tags: scala, generics, slick, database-agnostic

Basically what I want to achieve is a combination of:

[Slick 3.0.0 database agnostism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105571/slick-3-0-0-database-agnostism)
and 
[Slick 3 reusable generic repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522128/slick-3-reusable-generic-repository)

I tried a lot, actually, but I can't get this to work at all.

```
abstract class BaseModel[T <: slick.lifted.AbstractTable[_]](query: TableQuery[T], val driver: JdbcProfile, val dbTableName: String)
{
  lazy val all: TableQuery[T] = TableQuery[T]
  import driver.api._

  def createTable = all.schema.create
  def dropTable = all.schema.create

  abstract class BaseTable[B](val tag: Tag) extends Table[B](tag, dbTableName)
  {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  }
}
```

Now here we have a problem already:

`def createTable = all.schema.create` and the same with `dropTable...` -> `schema` cannot be resolved here, although I import the driver before.

But an even bigger problem comes in when I subclass this:

Here is the code

```
class NodeModel(driver: JdbcProfile, dbTableName: String) extends BaseModel[NodeTable](TableQuery[NodeTable], driver, dbTableName) {

  val dbDriver = driver
  import dbDriver.api._

  class NodeTable(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Node](tag)
  {
    override def * = id.? <> (Node, Node.unapply)
  }

  //lazy val all: TableQuery[NodeTable] = TableQuery[NodeTable]
  def createTable: DBIO[Unit] = all.schema.create
  def dropTable: DBIO[Unit] = all.schema.drop 
  def insert(node: Node) = all += node
}
```

This won't compile obviously because I cannot pass `NodeTable` as `T`, but gives an idea of what I want to achieve.

Do you have any idea how to solve this? I also tried with companion objects, moving the `BaseTable` out of the `BaseModel` and trying to load a `simpleDriver`... but it looks like that functionality was removed from Slick in a recent version :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Database agnostic and Code is highly reusable**

***I am using `Slick` with `Playframework` and this is how I achieved database agnostic and generic repository.***

***Note that this work is inspired from Active Slick***

*I want to have basic crud operations like this to be defined on my `case class`. I should be able to do `count`, `update`, `delete` and `create`. I want to write the curd code just once and reuse it for ever.*

Here is the snippet which demonstrates this.

```
case class Dog(name: String, id: Option[Long] = None)
Dog("some_dog").save()
Dog("some_dog").insert()
Dog("some_dog", Some(1)).delete()
```

*CrudActions.scala*

```
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext


trait CrudActions {
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  type Model

  def count: DBIO[Int]

  def save(model: Model)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Model]

  def update(model: Model)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Model]

  def delete(model: Model)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int]

  def fetchAll(fetchSize: Int = 100)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): StreamingDBIO[Seq[Model], Model]
}
```

*Now lets get our `Entity` into picture. Note that `Entity` is nothing but our case class*

*`Entity` is `case class` on which we do crud operations. For locating our entity lets also have `Id` in place. `Id` is important for locating and operating an entity or record in the database. Also `Id` uniquely identities for entity*

*EntityActionsLike.scala*

```
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait EntityActionsLike extends CrudActions {
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  type Entity

  type Id

  type Model = Entity

  def insert(entity: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Id]

  def deleteById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int]

  def findById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity]

  def findOptionById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Option[Entity]]
}
```

*Now lets implement these methods. For doing operations we need `Table` and `TableQuery`. Lets say we have `table` and `tableQuery`. The good about traits is we can declare a contract and leave the implementation details to subclasses or subtypes*

*EntityActions.scala*

```
import slick.ast.BaseTypedType
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait EntityActions extends EntityActionsLike {
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  type EntityTable <: Table[Entity]

  def tableQuery: TableQuery[EntityTable]

  def $id(table: EntityTable): Rep[Id]

  def modelIdContract: ModelIdContract[Entity,Id]

  override def count: DBIO[Int] = tableQuery.size.result

  override def insert(entity: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Id] = {
    tableQuery.returning(tableQuery.map($id(_))) += entity
  }

  override def deleteById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int] = {
    filterById(id).delete
  }

  override def findById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity] = {
    filterById(id).result.head
  }

  override def findOptionById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Option[Entity]] = {
    filterById(id).result.headOption
  }

  override def save(model: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity] = {
    insert(model).flatMap { id =>
      filterById(id).result.head
    }.transactionally
  }

  override def update(model: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity] = {
    filterById(modelIdContract.get(model)).update(model).map { _ => model }.transactionally
  }

  override def delete(model: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int] = {
    filterById(modelIdContract.get(model)).delete
  }

  override def fetchAll(fetchSize: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): StreamingDBIO[Seq[Entity], Entity] = {
    tableQuery.result.transactionally.withStatementParameters(fetchSize = fetchSize)
  }

  def filterById(id: Id) = tableQuery.filter($id(_) === id)

  def baseTypedType: BaseTypedType[Id]

  protected implicit lazy val btt: BaseTypedType[Id] = baseTypedType

}
```

*ActiveRecord.scala*

```
import slick.dbio.DBIO

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext


abstract class ActiveRecord[R <: CrudActions](val repo: R) {
  def model: repo.Model
  def save()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[repo.Model] = repo.save(model)
  def update()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[repo.Model] = repo.update(model)
  def delete()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int] = repo.delete(model)
}
```

*ModelContract.scala*

```
case class ModelIdContract[A, B](get: A => B, set: (A, B) => A)
```

**How to Use**

*Sample.scala*

```
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.ast.BaseTypedType
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.{ActiveRecord, EntityActions, ModelIdContract}

case class Dog(name: String, id: Option[Long] = None)

@Singleton
class DogActiveRecord @Inject() (databaseConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends EntityActions {

  override val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = databaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]

  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  override def tableQuery = TableQuery(new Dogs(_))

  override def $id(table: Dogs): Rep[Id] = table.id

  override def modelIdContract: ModelIdContract[Dog, Id] = ModelIdContract(dog => dog.id.get, (dog, id) => dog.copy(id = Some(id)))

  override def baseTypedType: BaseTypedType[Id] = implicitly[BaseTypedType[Id]]

  override type Entity = Dog
  override type Id = Long
  override type EntityTable = Dogs

  class Dogs(tag: Tag) extends Table[Dog](tag, "DogsTable") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def * = (name, id.?) <> (Dog.tupled, Dog.unapply)
  }

  implicit class ActiveRecordImplicit(val model: Entity) extends ActiveRecord(this)

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val result = Dog("some_dog").save()

  val res2 = Dog("some_other_dog", Some(1)).delete()

  val res3 = Dog("some_crazy_dog", Some(1)).update()
}
```

Now we can do operations on `Dog` directly like this

```
Dog("some_dog").save()
```

*This implicit does the magic for us*

```
implicit class ActiveRecordImplicit(val model: Entity) extends ActiveRecord(this)
```

*You can also add `scheme` creation and dropping logic in EntityActions*

```
tableQuery.schema.create
table.schema.drop
```

Comment: Apart from the ActiveRectord pattern I very much like that and will try it out asap! Thanks good Sir!

Comment: Can you also provide help with making the Table-definitions extendable?

Comment: How would you implement foreignKeys? Like if you had a DogRelation or the like that references to Dog.id

Comment: @Sorona You could do that in similar way ... makes changes in `EntityActions` and introduce new contracts

Comment: One more (very hard) question for you: How would you add in another layer. Say under Dog you want `Chihuahua` while `Dog` still should not be abstract. All you wanted to do was add another column to the db (so `Chihuahuas extends Dogs`). How would you go about this? I cannot seem to find a way because case classes cannot be extended, hence I cannot override `Entity` in `Chihuahua` and `EntityTable` neither :( I am totally stuck here. I understand how all of this works, but as soon as I add in another layer I am lost.